# Java Spring Problem with annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I've a problem with spring. I'm replacing the xml file based configuration of spring with annotation based configuration. Because of that I runned into the following problem. Theres is a class, where one field is configured by class based autowiring. Since yet, there has been only one candidate. But now there is more then one candidate, because I've added the @Named tag to mutliple classes of the same interface.

Here is a code example:
The class with the autowiring field:

```
public class AutowiringClass<X, Y> {
    // This is the field which is autowired
    private Autowired<X, Y> bean;
    .....
}
```

Then there is a second class, which extends AutoWiringClass with specific generic arguments:

```
public class TestClass extends AutoWiringClass<ObjectX, ObjectY> {
    .....
}
```

The Problem is, that spring doesn't know which class it should use, since there are more than once class of the type Autowiring but with different generic types (ObjectX, ObjectY). I thought, that the different generic types will do the thing.. but they doesn't :(
It would be awesome if anybody has an solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

[Qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) are what you are looking for. When you register a class as a Spring bean (using `@Component` or the like) you can pass a name as an argument. Then when you are autowiring a property, add a `@Qualifier` annotation with that bean's name. So:

```
@Component("Test1")
public class Test { }
@Component("Test2")
public class BetterTest extends Test {}

public class TestUser {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("Test1")
  private Test test;
}
```

Comment: No thats not I'm looking for. Sorry, I should had mentioned that, but I forogt. The problem is, that there are multiple TestClasses, that are extending AutoWiringClass. But in this TestClass the generics of the AutoWiringClass are different, but Java doesn't notice it :( And in the future there will be new TestClasses, but the Programmer of the TestClass should not care about setting the variable about a Qualifier, I hope there is a way to realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Generics won't help you due to *type erasure*, Spring can't do nothing about it. But you can either use `@Primary` annotation to denote the default implementation that should be always used or switch to autowiring by name rather than by type. Then Spring will use field name when in doubt.